# Apache Camel in Karaf always reconnects to server after put a message

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have installed Apache Camel 3.21.0 in Apache Karaf and installed camel-amqp feature. I created a CamelContext in blueprint (XML format) and used AMQPComponent to route messages from a topic in Apache ActiveMQ Artemis to another topic in the same server.

```
<camelContext xmlns="...">
    <route>
        <from uri="server:topic:topic.OUT" />
        <to uri="server:topic:topic.IN" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
<bean id="server" class="org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent>
     <property name="connectionFactory">
         <bean class="org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory">
             <property name="remoteURI" value="amqp://localhost:5672" />
             <property name="username" value="camel" />
             <property anme="password" value="camel" />
         </bean>
     </property>
</bean>
```

Camel routes all messages successfully, however, there are a lot of log messages appear in the Karaf.

```
[AmqpProvider] Connection ID: xxx connected to server: xxx
```

If I remove <to> tag, those log messages will stop appearing so I assume that the problem is Camel reconnect to the server after put a message to the topic.

How to force Camel to remain connect to the server? or how to force AmqpProvider not log those messages?

Thank you